# Autoposting on facebook page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am trying to create a simple web app, that when someone posts a message in the app, automatically posts an info about it on a facebook page. Ideally it would use a permanent token for the posting.

I have created an app and a page, and obtained a page access token using the app secret. However when I try to post a message to the page with this token, I get:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200)
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Now all I find in the docs regarding authorizing app to publish on page requires users to give the authorization by FB Login. I don't however want the the admin to login every time she tries to post something. I want to give the app a permanent permission to post on the page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way with a help from people on IRC. This is the flow that can be used:

Go to Graph API explorer. Select your application from the upper dropdown. Select your page from the bottom dropdown (generate page access token). Select the 'Request publish pages' option.
Copy the access token. Now exchange this token to a more long-lived one. Issue the following GET request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=<your token>&client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret>
```

The `app_id` and `app_secret` can be obtained from the application page.

The token you obtained will live 60 days, so you need to refresh it periodically. It can be used however to post to your page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of asking each time for the user authorization, this is just because you didn't specify the required scope to be able to [publish a new post on a linked page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed#publish) :

> A page access token with **publish_pages** permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

So you need to add the **PUBLISH_PAGES** in `perms` when you're [getting your access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens).

**UPDATE**

1. You first need to [get the user permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/authentication#access_token) by redirecting the user to this url (via a link or a back-end redirect) :

   ```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
   ?client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>
   &redirect_uri=<URL_TO_WHICH_USER_WILL_BE_REDIRECTED_ONCE_HE_CLICKED_OK_OR_CANCEL>
   &scope=publish_pages
   ```
2. In this url to which the user has been redirected, you will have have a this GET parameter :

   ```
   ?code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>
   ```
3. You then need to use this authorization code to get a token (from your back-end) by calling this url (FYI current API version is `v2.6`) :

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/oauth/access_token
   ?client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>
   &redirect_uri=<THE_HIDDEN_URL_CALLED_BACK_WITH_JSON_DATA_IN_THE_BODY>
   &client_secret=<YOUR_APP_SECRET>
   &code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>
   ```
4. In this hidden url that's called back, you'll get a JSON in the body that should look like that :

   ```
   {
       status: 'connected',
       authResponse: {
           accessToken: '...',
           expiresIn:'...',
           signedRequest:'...',
           userID:'...'
       }
   }
   ```
5. You can now store this access token (generally in a database) to execute actions on behalf of this user, in your case that is publishing posts on the wall of his page.

---

aiohttp gives you many example on [how to call these urls](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#make-a-request) and [how to retrieve their content](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#response-content).

To get a real-life example, you have [this nice tutorial](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-build-facebook-hello-world-web-app-python/how-to/2015/10/05?page=2), which is using Flask, but that's really easy to adapt it with aiohttp methods.

A last advice : since it seems that you're not used with APIs management, I still suggest you to use the [Facebook Python SDK](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) because it's way easier when you're a beginner and you'll get a rich list of tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, but how? The page you linked (I already read it before) doesn't say, how to specify perms when asking for an access token.

Comment: Which language do you use ? Which framework ? Do you use a SDK ?

Comment: I'm planning to use Python + aiohttp. I was hoping, I wouldn't need any SDK, just sending http requests to the graph API. Is it possible?

Comment: @zefciu Obviouly that's possible, I edited my question to explain you the complete roadmap about how to get an access token adapted to your case.

Comment: No. It is not adapted to my case. I explicitly stated that I don't want to use login.

Comment: But you said *on **a** facebook page*, not *on **my** facebook page*. Your token will only work for your own pages. Next time try to be more specific, it will avoid wasting other's time to answer...